# Is Ubuntu One ignoring particular directory names?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Under "Ubuntu One" in my home directory (using 11.04) I have a directory "daily" and under that 7 more directories whose names are the days of the week.
A daily cron job gathers a few important files and puts them in the proper subdirectory so that I have backups for the most recent 7 days. Works fine.
When I log on to one.ubuntu.com/files, all the directories and most of the files are there, but the files under daily/Wednesday and daily/Thursday are missing.

I've tried waiting. Several days. The wednesday and thursday files that I can see locally does not get uploaded.
I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting ubuntu one in the Ubuntu One control panel. Does not help.
If I create an empty file under daily/Friday, it gets uploaded within seconds. Doing the same under daily/Wednesday has no effect.
I've checked that the file and group owner and protection bits are the same for all files. File sizes are also similar for all directories. The total size of all files is less than 100Mb, so should fit within the 2GB limit.

What more can I try?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! I think it will be easier to help you if you provide the scripts you use with cron. That'll enable others to try to reproduce your problem and hopefully they'll find what's causing it.

Comment: I found one thing that worked! moving all the files out of ~/Ubuntu One, so only the "Shared With Me" link remained, and then moving everything back again. Now all the files got uploaded. Weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving all the files out of ~/Ubuntu One and then back again helped - the files that were not uploaded after a disconnect/reconnect were now uploaded.

As for why it didn't work before, I can only speculate - some of the files were previously owned by root and were perhaps skipped by the ubuntu-one daemon because of that.
The directory monitoring perhaps only notices file delete/create but not change of ownership.